# HP ALM REST API Get Requirements Coverage

Tags: hp-quality-center

Is there any way to get the requirement coverage matrix from a specific `domain/project/requirements/id` ?

As I read from the REST API Help you can only get the number of covering items [test] but not the ids oh those test.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can get access to the coverage only from ALM 11.50 so if you have something below that you may be out of luck. See the REST requirement-coverages service. But even then it's under documented for now.

Answer (score -2):

Use query to get the details

```
SELECT REQ.RQ_REQ_ID, REQ.RQ_REQ_NAME, REQ_TYPE.TPR_NAME, REQ_COVER.RC_ENTITY_TYPE,
       REQ_COVER.RC_ENTITY_ID, TEST.TS_NAME, TEST.TS_TYPE,
       RUN.RN_RUN_ID, RUN.RN_RUN_NAME, RUN.RN_STATUS,
       RUN.RN_TESTER_NAME, CYCLE.CY_CYCLE
FROM REQ Left join REQ_TYPE on REQ_TYPE.TPR_TYPE_ID = REQ.RQ_TYPE_ID
         Left join REQ_COVER on REQ_COVER.RC_REQ_ID = REQ.RQ_REQ_ID
         Left join TEST on TEST.TS_TEST_ID = REQ_COVER.RC_ENTITY_ID
         Left Join RUN on RUN.RN_TEST_ID = TEST.TS_TEST_ID
         Left Join CYCLE on CYCLE.CY_CYCLE_ID = RUN.RN_CYCLE_ID
where RC_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TEST'
order by REQ.RQ_REQ_ID;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to get the coverage with the REST API.